# Filter within ErgoScript using Coll

Tags: ergoscript

I'd like to use the filter function in Coll. However I'm getting an error that says that there's something wrong with parsing:

Code:

```
        val isNftInDataInputBox: Boolean =
            dataInputBox.tokens
                .filter(token => token._1 == outProfileBox.R5[Coll[Byte]].get)
                .nonEmpty
```

Error:

```
Invalid declaration of lambda Ident(token,NoType) => Some(EQ(Select(Ident(token,NoType),_1,None),Select(ApplyTypes(Select(Ident(outProfileBox,NoType),R5,None),Vector(Coll[SByte$])),get,None)))
sigmastate.lang.syntax.ParserException: 
line 61:                 .filter(token => token._1 == outProfileBox.R5[Coll[Byte]].get)
```

Is Filter allowed in ErgoScript?

Is this the correct documentation for Colls?
https://github.com/ScorexFoundation/sigmastate-interpreter/blob/fada073b82a16a928c457693b888da4c0310aca6/library/src/main/scala/special/collection/impl/CollsImpl.scala

Answer (score 2):

I was able to filter it this way:

```
val filteredNFTToken: Coll[(Coll[Byte], Long)] = dataInputBox.tokens
  .filter{
    (token: (Coll[Byte], Long)) => token._1 == outProfileBox.R5[Coll[Byte]].get
  }

val isNftInDataInputBox: Boolean = filteredNFTToken.size == 1
```

However, when I try

```
filteredNFTToken.NonEmpty
```

it fails with

```
Cannot find method 'nonEmpty' in in the object Ident(filteredNFTToken,NoType) of Product type with methods List(SMethod(sigmastate.SCollection$@25a5c8e,size,(Coll[IV]) => SInt$,1,FixedCost(14),MethodIRInfo(None,None,None),Some(OperationInfo(Some(SizeOf$(177)),The size of the collection in elements.,ArrayBuffer(ArgInfo(this,this instance)))),None), SMethod(sigmastate.SCollection$@25a5c8e,getOrElse,[IV](Coll[IV],SInt$,IV) => IV,2,FixedCost(30),MethodIRInfo(Some(<function1>),None,None),Some(OperationInfo(Some(ByIndex$(178)),Return the element of collection if \lst{index} is in range \lst{0 .. size-1},ArrayBuffer(ArgInfo(this,this instance), ArgInfo(index,index of the element of this collection), ArgInfo(default,value to return when \lst{index} is out of range)))),None), SMethod(sigmastate.SCollection$@25a5c8e,map,[IV,OV](Coll[IV],(IV) => OV) => Coll[OV],3,PerItemCost(20,1,10),MethodIRInfo(None,None,None),Some(OperationInfo(Some(MapCollection$(173)), Builds a new collection by applying a function to all elements of this collection.
 Returns a new collection of type \lst{Coll[B]} resulting from applying the given function
 \lst{f} to each element of this collection and collecting the results.
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for available methods is [1](https://github.com/ScorexFoundation/sigmastate-interpreter/blob/develop/docs/LangSpec.md#collt).
The `NonEmpty` of `nonEmpty` methods are not available on Coll type.
Note, the names are case sensitive.

So, your solution is the right way to go.